# OpenCL enqueue barrier vs enqueue marker - what's the difference?

Tags: synchronization, opencl, barrier

The OpenCL specification  has the API functions:

- [`clEnqueueMarkerWithWaitList()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/specs/2.2/html/OpenCL_API.html#clEnqueueMarkerWithWaitList)
- [`clEnqueueBarrierWithWaitList()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/specs/2.2/html/OpenCL_API.html#clEnqueueMarkerWithWaitList)

<sub>(I'm looking at v2.2 but they exist in v3.0 as well.)</sub>

Not only do they have an identical signature, they also have very similar descriptions. What is the *difference* between these two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer assumes the common case where OpenCL command queues are in-order queues. Out of order queues are less common and require a more fine grained synchronization.

A simple way to see the difference between a marker and a barrier is by looking at the most typical use case scenario of each one of them. From a point of view of an asynchronous program:

- A marker is typically used by a **producer**.
- A barrier is typically used by a **consumer**.

So you would typically us them in scenarios where commands on one queue can't begin execution before a command on a different queue has finished.

Example:
Assume you have 2 command queues: queue1 and queue2. And two associated kernels: kernel1 and kernel2 respectively. kernel1 writes to a buffer (cl_mem) that kernel2 reads.

A sequence of command recording (on a single thread) could look like that:

```
queue1.enqueue(kernel1) 
event1 = queue1.enqueue_marker() // event 1 will signal only after kernel 1 is done
queue2.enqueue_barrier(wait_list = event1) // kernel 2 will not start before event1 is signaled
queue2.enqueue(kernel2)
```

The reason you rarely see markers and barriers used in real code is that each `clEnqueue***` API call implicitly act as a marker and a barrier. You typically use barriers and markers if you don't have access to the raw `clEnqueue***` calls.

For example:

```
cl_int clEnqueueNDRangeKernel ( cl_command_queue command_queue,
    cl_kernel kernel,
    cl_uint work_dim,
    const size_t *global_work_offset,
    const size_t *global_work_size,
    const size_t *local_work_size,
    cl_uint num_events_in_wait_list,
    const cl_event *event_wait_list, // barrier
    cl_event *event) // marker
```

The returned event **marks** the end of the enqueued command (and also all previous commands, in the case of in-order queue). You may provide the returned event to a consumer command (clEnqueue***) on a different queue (as wait list) to be used a a barrier.

Comment: 1. Sometimes you need to wait until some commands have executed without starting another command, so a barrier makes sense then even when you can clEnqueueWhatever. 2. Isn't the difference you describe between marker and barrier purely a matter of convention? i.e. in your first code snippet, could I not simply switch the uses of `enqueue_barrier` and `enqueue_marker` and get the same behavior?

Comment: 1. In order to wait for a bunch of commands, you could wait on the event associated with the last command. Or enqueue a marker and wait on the returned event.
2. You could potentially use the waitlist argument of the marker to get a barrier-like behavior. at least on an in order queue where there is implicit synchronization between commands on the same queue.
a barrier without a wait list just to mark an event seems weird. but might work I guess.

Answer (score 0):

If you read a bit into the description for the barrier you will see that, unlike the marker, it says

> This command blocks command execution, that is, any following commands enqueued after it do not execute until it completes.